# How to avoid text break of paragraph next to floated image while preserving responsiveness?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, less

I am using latest Bootstrap with LESS.

I have built a grid of articles that contain an image floated to the left and next to it a paragraph:

[image]

**HTML:**

```
<!-- featured articles -->
    <div id="featured-articles" class="container">


      <!-- row -->
      <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-6">

          <img src="http://placehold.it/265x150">

          <h4>Article Header</h4>

          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
          tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
          quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex... <a href="#">Read More</a></p>

        </div>


        <div class="col-md-6">

          <img src="http://placehold.it/265x150">

          <h4>Article Header</h4>

          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
          tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
          quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex... <a href="#">Read More</a></p>

        </div>

      </div><!-- row -->

</div><!-- /featured articles -->
```

**LESS:**

```
#featured-articles {


    padding-bottom: 25px;

    img {
        display: block;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding-bottom: 15px;
        clear: both;
    }

    p {
        text-align: justify;
    }

    h4 {
        margin-top: 0px;
    }


    @media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) {

        img {
            float: left;
            padding-right: 10px;
            padding-bottom: 0px;
        }

        .col-md-6 {
            padding-bottom: 25px;
            margin-bottom: 25px;
        }

    }

}
```

Now the problem is that on certain smaller resolutions, the text from the right is starting to break instead of keeping the alignment of the paragraph:

[image]

Is there a way to keep the text nicely aligned instead of breaking while keeping it responsive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally you would wrap the text and set a margin-left. In this case around 270px.

```
p {
    text-align: justify;
    margin-left: 270px;
}
```

Here is an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/f7ohrLrs/

Answer (score 0):

To me, it looks like on smaller resolutions your text is scaling down but your image size is staying intact, because of which text tries to make room for itself by coming down.

You can try using `img-responsive` class on your `img` tag

```
<img src="..." class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image">
```

For more info: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images

Comment: Image responsiveness is not the problem here. The problem is the Text paragraph next to the image that should be kept aligned and not flow under the image.

Comment: Does your images decrease in size when you view on smaller resolutions, where your text is coming under image? If not, try adding `img-responsive` class on `img` tag, that will scale image according to resolution making room for text.